# Loading page and Overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

I'm using this code for active a overlay that will cover all the page:

```
    <div class="overlay">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KUJoe.gif">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.overlay').fadeOut();
    });
    </script>
```

And I added in the style.css:

```
.overlay{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:99999;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  transition: 1s 0.4s;
}
```

But not works. Where I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the snippet, i think you just need to set the width and the height to 100%, and you just need to set top and left prop, so in the snippet i centralize a loading gif just to show you the class `overlay` working.

```css
.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
.overlay>img{
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <img src="http://gifyo.com/public/img/loading.gif"/>
</div>
<h2>Test<h2/>
```

Comment: I tested better, works but fadeOut(); not close the overlay.

Comment: Solved. The code with fadeOut was before of loading of JQuery. Now works all. Thanks.